# Create Sequence In Migration Not Reflected In Schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application that requires a sequence to be present in the database. I have a migration that does the following:

```
class CreateSequence < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "CREATE SEQUENCE sequence"
  end

  def self.down
    execute "DROP SEQUENCE sequence"
  end
end
```

This does not modify the `schema.rb` and thus breaks `rake db:setup`. How can I force the schema to include the sequence?

Note: The sequence exists after running `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: What rails version and db are you using?

Comment: @Kevin - what Rails version are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rails Migrations because they aim toward a schema of tables and fields, instead of a complete database representation including stored procedures, functions, seed data.

When you run rake db:setup, this will create the db, load the schema and then load the seed data.

A few solutions for you to consider:

Choice 1: create your own rake task that does these migrations independent of the Rails Migration up/down. Rails Migrations are just normal classes, and you can make use of them however you like. For example:

```
rake db:create_sequence
```

Choice 2: run your specific migration after you load the schema like this:

```
rake db:setup
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000
```

Choice 3: create your sequence as seed data, because it's essentially providing data (rather than altering the schema).

```
db/seeds.rb
```

Choice 4 and my personal preference: run the migrations up to a known good point, including your sequence, and save that blank database. Change rake db:setup to clone that blank database. This is a bit trickier and it sacrifices some capabilities - having all migrations  be reversible, having migrations work on top of multiple database vendors, etc. In my experience these are fine tradeoffs. For example:

```
rake db:fresh  #=> clones the blank database, which you store in version control
```

Answer (score 4):

All the above suggestions are good. however, I think I found a better solution. basically in your development.rb put

```
    config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

For more info see my answer to this issue - 
[rake test not copying development postgres db with sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942460/rake-test-not-copying-development-postgres-db-with-sequences/11767470#11767470)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [pg_sequencer](https://github.com/code42/pg_sequencer) gem. It manages Pg sequences for you as you wish. The one flaw that I can see right now is that it doesn't play nicely with `db/schema.rb` -- Rails will generate a `CREATE SEQUENCE` for your tables with a `serial` field, and `pg_sequencer` will **also** generate a sequence itself. (Working to fix that.)