# How to add a database domain in Activerecord without executing a raw SQL query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to create a database domain, for example, like this one:

```
CREATE DOMAIN colour AS VARCHAR CHECK (VALUE IN ('red', 'green', 'blue'));
```

How do I do this in Rails Activerecord without executing the raw SQL query in a migration?
Another concern is, how do I reflect the domain creation in schema.rb?
Is there any gem for it?

My setup is PostgreSQL 9.6 and Rails 5.0.

I expect there to be a method like `enable_extension` ([docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter/enable_extension)) or `create_trigger` as in hair_trigger gem ([link](https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger)).

Comment: What is wrong with executing raw SQL?

Comment: I used to run same with `ActiveRecord::Migration.execute(query_string)`

Comment: Raw SQLs are not reflected in schema.rb

Comment: OK, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949777/9262523) provides a good alternative: add the query to seeds.rb, as it is part of `rails db:setup`. This needs to be tested though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is infact writing a migration with raw SQL for this

```
class ExampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        # create color ype
        execute <<-SQL
          CREATE DOMAIN colour AS VARCHAR CHECK (VALUE IN ('red', 'green', 'blue'));
        SQL
      end

      dir.down do
        # drop color type
        execute <<-SQL
          DROP DOMAIN colour;
        SQL
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then you can setup a rake task that runs these migrations as described here in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144556/create-sequence-in-migration-not-reflected-in-schema/9949777#9949777)

Comment: This answers neither of the questions, unfortunately. Most importantly, it doesn't solve the problem of adding said changes to schema.rb.
I upvoted your answer, because I acknowledge that a rake task could do for a workaround, though it's not convenient and can therefore be messed up (for example, after a long period of time passes or if project gets another team).

Comment: @TimurNugmanov I agree but I think thats the best option you have at the moment. You could also try `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` which should make the migration reflect on the schema file but I would rather have my default schema format

Comment: As soon as you start needing database-specific features you'll want to [switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47879896/479863) from [`schema.rb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31955422/479863) to [`db/structure.sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509650/479863). There's a little more to it than just switching `schema_format` to `:sql` but not much. BTW, if you `change` is jut a `reversible` call, separate `up` and `down` methods might be clearer and will use less indentation.